# Static files not loading on Multisite WordPress in NGINX

Tags: wordpress, nginx, multisite

I have installed multisite in a subdirectory of the main WordPress for a single domain.

However, the WordPress sites are loading perfectly including the inner pages, except the multisite that is installed as a subdirectory.

```
{% set sites = [
    'site1',
    'site2',
    'site3',
    'multisite'
] %}

{% set multisites = [
    'multisite1',
    'multisite2',
    'multisite3',
] %}


{% for site in sites %}
    location /{{ site }} {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /{{ site }}/index.php?$args;
    }
{% endfor %}

{% for site in multisites %}
    location /multisite/{{ site }} {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /multisite/index.php?$args;
    }
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can it is because of  ```multisite``` and ```multisites```?

Comment: Multisite was only the sample naming for the name of the main WordPress.